Confusion about orientation of line integral
Consider a continuous curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parameterized by $\mathbf{r}(t)$ as $t:a \rightarrow b$. Now, it is my understanding that line integrals
$$
\int_\gamma \phi \ ds
$$
for a scalar field $\phi$ does not depend on the orientation of $\gamma$.
My confusion arises as follows. It is my understanding that $\mathbf{r}(t)$ still corresponds to the curve in question but with reversed orientation if we let $t:b \rightarrow a$. But if this is the case we get
$$
\int_\gamma \phi \ ds = \int_a^b \phi \| \dot{\mathbf{r}} \| \ dt \neq \int_b^a \phi \| \dot{\mathbf{r}} \| \ dt = \int_{\gamma_{\text{rev}}} \phi \ ds.
$$
Anyone see what I'm missing? Any help is appreciated!

There should be a negative sign introduced when you switch from a forward parameterization to a backward parameterization.

If you reverse orientation you are actually doing $\mathbf{r}(-t)$.  The chain rule gives your missing minus sign.

Hmm, okay. I guess I don't understand why $\mathbf{r}(t)$ when $t:b \rightarrow a$ would not suffice? Why am I using $\mathbf{r}(-t)$? If so, am I going from $a$ to $b$ or vice versa?

Suppose you have $\mathbf{r}(t) = \langle f(t), g(t) \rangle$ for $a \leq t \leq b$, that is, domain $[a,b]$.  Neither $b \leq t \leq a$ nor $[b,a]$ make sense, so when you go backwards you are actually changing to the new path $\mathbf{s}(t)=\mathbf{r}(-t) = \langle f(-t), g(-t) \rangle$ for $-b \leq t \leq -a$, that is, domain $[-b,-a]$.  Now if you carefully write down the integrals your minus sign issue goes away.  Your mistake is thinking that just saying $t: b \to a$ makes the path run backwards, when it actually doesn't make any sense when you look at the **definition ** of a path.

@SamKirkiles How come? Is this just a definition? In other words, are we just defining $\int_\gamma \phi , d s= \operatorname{sgn}(b-a) \int_a^b \phi(\mathbf{r}(t))|\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)| , d t$?

@Randall Alright, it seems my vector analysis textbook is using quite an unusual definition of orientation. By this definition the curve is indeed reversed by simply saying $t: b \rightarrow a$. This made sense to me intuitively, because a domain $[a,b]$ has no intrinsic relation to traversals. I now understand that almost everyone else necessitates the parameter to grow in an interval, and that the interval must be chosen accordingly.

@Incubu121  You are correct, there should be no extra minus sign in a $ds$ integral when reversing the orientation.  There will be one for $d\mathbf{r}$ integrals.
